# How to send payments from one PayPal Business account to another?

Tags: php, laravel, paypal

I've integrated the PayPal payment gateway, but now I need to know whether PayPal can handle the below scenario.

Let's say a customer pays $1000 which includes a non-refundable $100 application fee. Later the customer cancels and receives $800 as there is also a $10 cancellation fee, so the formula looks like:

`$refund_amount($800) = $total_amount($1000) - $cancellation_charge($100) - $application_fee($100)`

So now my business account has balance of $200 and I want to transfer `cancellation_fee($100)` to my service provider's PayPal account and want to keep `application_fee($100)` in my account. This transfer is the step I need help with.

Initially all payment has been received by the app owner account and later if the customer cancels or completes the booking amount must transfer to the provider's account (minus the $100 application fee)

I have gone through some PayPal API docs but was unable to find any solution for the transfer.

I'm using the **paypal/rest-api-sdk-php** library in Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

For receiving payments, do not use the v1 PayPal-PHP-SDK; it is deprecated.  Use the cureen v2 Checkout-PHP-SDK.  Implement two routes on your server, one for "Set Up Transaction" and one for "Capture Transaction", documented here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/

For the payer to give their approval, pair your two routes with: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

---

For automating sending payments from one of your accounts to another account, use the Payouts-PHP-SDK. The account sending payments will need to be approved for PayPal Payouts. See here regarding requesting approval: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/payouts/integrate/prerequisites/#get-access-to-paypal-payouts